# contracts.d cannot be read

Tags: d, dmd

I recently unzipped the subdirs windows and src from [dmd.2.060.zip](https://github.com/downloads/D-Programming-Language/dmd/dmd.2.060.zip). Then I tried to `import std.contracts;` but the compiler did not like it:

```
Error: module contracts is in file 'std\contracts.d' which cannot be read
```

I could not find the file by hand either. What is broken ?

Have contracts.d been replaced by another file ?

Maybe I must compile something before use ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `std.exception` module now.